# Java:Reading from a file and outputting it whiling suming and avging

Tags: java, input, sum, output, average

I need to read from a file that has 10 numbers like:
1
2
...
10

and read those back into the program and add those up and avg them.
Only problem is is that I don't know for the life of me how to change those into
addable numbers?  I haven't learned arrays yet so I'm still a beginner.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class inputoutput {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{


    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

    outputFile.println("1");
    outputFile.println("2");
    outputFile.println("3");
    outputFile.println("4");
    outputFile.println("5");
    outputFile.println("6");
    outputFile.println("7");
    outputFile.println("8");
    outputFile.println("9");
    outputFile.println("10");
    outputFile.close();


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("output.txt")); 
    String text = in.readLine();
    while (in.ready()) { 
          text = in.readLine(); 
          System.out.println(text);
        }
    in.close();
```

To be perfectly honestly I got that bufferReader code off the internet to help me along
but I have no idea why it only displays from 2 to 10 rather than starting with 1.
Then I'm lost on how to convert those to numbers so that I can add them all together then 
avg them.

help?

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the String to get an int like

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
```

But also bear in mind that this assumes that `text` is really a convertible String.

If you want a simple validation you could do

```
int num = 0;
while ((text = in.readLine()) != null)
     try {
          num = Integer.parseInt(text);
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          //do something here when you have a String that cannot be converted e.g. "19a"
          num = 0;
     }

     System.out.println(text);
}
```

**Edit**: I also suggest you use the `while` condition I put above. Currently you are reading a line before the loop even begins.

Comment: would that only return 1 number to the value num?

Comment: It will return `1` when it's in the first row (based on your example) and `2` when in the second and so on.

Comment: Well I think I understood that much, but I'm wondering how you set each one to a variable like num1 (is first line) num 2 (is second line) so on and so forth. That's how I seems to make sense out of it.

Comment: You don't need to do that. You could just declare variables like `sum` and just add to it every time you read a line and a variable like `numCount` to keep track how many lines are read. Then you can get your average.

Answer (score 0):

`text` get `"1"` at line1, but is changed to `"2"` soon at line3.
so, `"1"` is never printed.

Change line1 as below.

```
String text = "";
```